# SP2013: spPageContextInfo.userId - how to get address of currently logged in user

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have this part of code:

```
function getUser() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    //alert(userid);

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var loginName = data.d.Title;
        var street = data.d.???;
        var city = data.d.???;
        var postalCode = data.d.???;
        var mobilePhone = data.d.???;
        var Email = data.d.Email;
        console.log(loginName);
        console.log(street);
        console.log(city);
        console.log(postalCode);
        console.log(mobilePhone);
        console.log(Email);

    } function onError(error) {
        alert("Error getting user.");
    }
}
```

and what I need is how to get other user info than Title and Email..

For example: the output should look like this:

```
John Doe (Title)
5th Ave. 100 (street)
New York (city)
123 456 (postalCode)
111 222 333 (mobilePhone)
johndoe@emai.com (Email)
```

Is it possible to do it using _spPageContextInfo.userId? Or is there any ther way to do it? To get it directly form AD?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming that you have user profile configured, you can hit the endpoint `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` which will get all the properties

Comment: so instead of /_api/web/getuserbyid I should put in /_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties??

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: it does not work